# Washing Machine(WM) installation: Water box

Tags: water, washer

Location: West Bengal, India.
Electrical supply: 240V AC.
Model: IFB TL-SDR 6.5 Kg Aqua.

Question:
Will a water box provide any advantage, now or later, if the WM model is changed? Should I include one with a hammer arrestor?

[image: washing machine installed]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

Water Box:

[image: washing machine connection box]
<sup>[Source](https://www.ubuy.co.in/search/index/view/product/B00PB9DZLQ/s/eastman-60245-washing-machine-outlet-box-1-2-inch-pex-recessed-pvc-double-drain-white/store/store/kk/dp?ref_p=dp-rp)</sup>

Comment: Considering those installation instructions, I would conclude with almost 100% certainty that your machine does not have a waste pump.

Comment: While these are all questions about installing _your_ washing machine, they really are 3 separate questions, and it's entirely possible that you'll have 3 people answer each of them, making it very difficult to select a "best" answer. According to the rules of this site, please break this up into 3 separate questions so that you can get good answers to each of them.

Comment: Many thanks, I will do that.

Comment: Edited question, under one topic.

Comment: Many thanks for all the observations.